# ws02 ELB(elastic load balancer)

Tags: wso2

Could you please help me to configure the ELB for ESB clustering. I am using 9443 port for manager node.

I am getting port no already in use.

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Comment: Your details are not good enough. Without knowing what you have configured, how can we help. Also, WSO2 ELB is discontinued for some time now. WSO2 recommends a load balancer such as Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the Port conflict issue you can offset one of the products. Open /repository/conf/carbon.xml and edit the following property.

```
<Offset>10</Offset>
```

As a side note WSO2 ELB is deprecated hence you can use a recommended LB like Nginx or Apache2.